# free public databases with non-trivial table structures?

Tags: sql, database, rdbms

I'm looking for some sample database data that I can use for testing and demonstrating a DB tool I am working on.  I need a DB that has (preferably) many tables, and many foreign key relationships between the tables.

Ideally the data would be in SQL dump format, or at least in something that maintains the foreign key references, and could be easily imported into an RDBMS (MySQL or H2).

The dataset itself doesn't have to be huge (in fact, best if it's not). I thought about using the [Stackoverflow Data Dump](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/stack-overflow-creative-commons-data-dump/), but it's only about 5 tables.

Answer (score 1):

What about using the entire [Wikipedia database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia_database)?

Comment: And if that's too big (quite possible), maybe the "current versions only" dump.

Comment: Hmm, I actually considered that, but the *compressed* "pages-articles" archive is 5.7GB, is XML, and I'm not quite sure which tables it includes. I'm afraid it'll be a bit unwieldy.

Comment: @Caffeine Coma - The pages one only includes the pages table. And uncompressed I think it is rather huge. But you can get the other tables as well.

Answer (score 1):

I should learn to RTFM- MySQL has a sample database for exactly this kind of thing.  It's called [Sakila](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/sakila/en/sakila.html). It's small, but it does have a good number of connected tables.  I'm still eager to hear more suggestions though.

Comment: Maybe browse some of the open source projects on SourceForge to see if any of them come with a database you can use.